# BitmapImage Constuctor(Uri) not working on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, uri, windows-phone-7.1, bitmapimage

```
BitmapImage tempBitmap = new BitmapImage(onlineImageLocation);
```

Fairly simple code. OnlineImageLocation refers to http://dantonybrown.com/brownsoft/SweepyCleaner.png

but after construction BitMap image contains no poplated fields. Even PixelWidth and PixelHeight are 0.

Any ideas?

Danny

Answer (score 2):

For instance like this?

```
    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://dantonybrown.com/brownsoft/SweepyCleaner.png"));
    MessageBox.Show(bmpImage.PixelWidth.ToString());
```

That makes perfect sense. The image is loaded on demand, and on the background. You have multiple options here:

1. Assign the BitmapImage to an Image control. You can access the properties after the ImageLoaded event occured:

   ```
       BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://dantonybrown.com/brownsoft/SweepyCleaner.png"));
       bmpImage.ImageOpened += (sender, args) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(
           bmpImage.PixelWidth.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
       imageCtrl.Source = bmpImage;
   ```
2. Load the BitmapImage with CreateOptions.None. This will still load the image in the background, but you don't have to assign the image to a control before it starts loading:

   ```
       BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://dantonybrown.com/brownsoft/SweepyCleaner.png"))
                                  {CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None};
       bmpImage.ImageOpened += (sender, args) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(
           bmpImage.PixelWidth.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
   ```